ASP.NET MVC controller method receives an empty instance of object instead of the null value, why?
I have - formally expressed - an IActionResult Index(object? obj) controller method in an ASP.NET MVC project. If I call it by the main menu from the web frontend without any route values, it is generating an empty object of the input parameter instead of the null value, but why?
Brief explanation: one part of my project is an employee administration system. The index page of Employees shows a list of employees depending on the area which they belong to. And if no area has been selected, all employees are displayed. When the Index page is called for the first time, there is no selection of an area, and therefore I expect the variable in the controller method to have the value null.
In concrete terms, this means that my controller method looks like this (exemplary):
public IActionResult Index(Area? area)
{
    if (area == null)
    {
        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        return View(area.Id);
    }
}

And the corresponding Area class, like this:
public class Area
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    // ...
}

I call the Index method via:
<a class="nav-link" asp-controller="Employees" asp-action="Index">Employees</a>

Because of there are no route values or similar. I expect that the variable area in my controller method == null. But it is an empty Area object, as can be seen below (in the mean time I tried to define a default value  == null. As you can see in the screenshot. But it doesn't work either)
Value of area at runtime:


Do you need a [FromBody] attribute ?  (You shouldn't, but it's worth checking if that's all it is).

No, a [FormBody] results in a 415 HTTP Error for the GET Request. But your proposal gives me an idea: why not send the null value via the route values. And that finally brought me to the following article: link There is to read "For complex Types, model binding creates an instance by using the default constructor, without setting properties." It seems to be the standard behaviour of the model binding extension. But I found a workaround which will soon be in the answers.

Neil's trigger gave me the idea of trying to send the null value via the route values. That didn't work with an Area object either, but finally it gave me the following workaround:
    public IActionResult Index(int? areaId)
    {
        Area? area = _context.Areas.Find(areaId);
        // if areaId == `null` the .Find() command returns `null`
        ...
    }

So I can send the null value via areaId and get a null Area object. I think it's a bit more charming then checking if area.Id == 0 for the option "All areas" because there may be an area with Id == 0
Thanks for your help
